# How to use template parameter with extras.execute_values()?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using extras.execute_values() method in psycopg2 and things don't go throw as I expected:

```
countyid_landid_tuple_list = [(1,1),(1,2),(2,3)]
sql = "update agri_land set county_id = %s"
extras.execute_values(cur, sql, countyid_landid_tuple_list ,"%s where id = %s")
```

The error message is as follows:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: error:  grammar mistakes around "," or nearby
LINE 1: ...e agri_land set country_id = 1 where id = 1,1 where i...
```

Basically, the [documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers) is pretty bad about explaining the usage of template perameter. Why not more examples?

Environment:

- python        3.7.9(64-bit)
- psycopg2      2.9.5
- PostgreSQL    12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs do indeed cover this case. From :

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers

```
execute_values(cur,
... """UPDATE test SET v1 = data.v1 FROM (VALUES %s) AS data (id, v1)
... WHERE test.id = data.id""",
... [(1, 20), (4, 50)])
```

So:

```
countyid_landid_tuple_list = [(1,1),(1,2),(2,3)]
sql = "update agri_land set county_id = data.v1 from (values %s) as data(v1,id) where id = data.id"
extras.execute_values(cur, sql, countyid_landid_tuple_list)
```

Comment: My bad, it is that I just can't understand the grammar here at first sight even though you have helped me suit my case. After some typing, I think I kind of understand now. Gramercy, Sir.

Answer (score 1):

The psycopg2 extras.execute_values function is typically used for bulk-insert operations, not for bulk-update operations, because it structures queries in a way that does not easily allow for the WHERE clause to vary from row to row.

You can consider looping through your list of tuples and executing individual update statements.

```
countyid_landid_tuple_list = [(1,1),(1,2),(2,3)]
for county_id, land_id in countyid_landid_tuple_list:
    sql = "UPDATE agri_land SET county_id = %s WHERE id = %s"
    cur.execute(sql, (county_id, land_id))
```

If you have a large number of updates to make, you can utilize psycopg2's ability to batch and commit multiple updates at once:

```
countyid_landid_tuple_list = [(1,1),(1,2),(2,3)]
with psycopg2.connect(DSN) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        for county_id, land_id in countyid_landid_tuple_list:
            sql = "UPDATE agri_land SET county_id = %s WHERE id = %s"
            cur.execute(sql, (county_id, land_id))
        conn.commit()
```

This way, you still get the performance benefits of batching your updates into a single transaction. It won't be as fast as a bulk insert, but it should be more efficient than executing and committing each update individually.

Comment: This `... not for bulk-update operations, ...` is not true. See my answer for the example in the docs.

Comment: Thanks indeed for your generous help, I also tried the method you mentioned. It is always helpful to have an alternative choice.